# Is there an issue with calling toString() to avoid the type check [String? assigned to String]?

Tags: flutter

I have a class that has a String? field.

```
class CurrentSubscriber extends ChangeNotifier {
  String? _name;
  .
  .
}
```

I want a "Text" widget to show this field.

```
 Text(
      currentSubscriber.name,  // The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: leadingFontSize),
      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
 ),
```

The widget requires the string to of type String and not String. So I'm calling toString() on the field just to avoid this error. I think that's fine, because even if the field is null, it should display "null" or something to that effect.

Is there an issue I can't see with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toString()` as you say will print something like `null`, which may not be universally understood.

Consider using a null-aware operator like:

```
currentSubscriber.name ?? 'N/A';
```

Now you get to choose the value used when `name` is null - and could even internationalize it for different audiences, etc.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't consider that. This is better. Thank you.